# Why would I be getting this cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values error

Tags: python, database, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot two columns of a pandas dataframe. I have used pandas before but it has been a while. I am trying to plot by simply doing:

```
df.plot.scatter(df['Time of Last Submission'], df['Last Attempt'])
```

My dataframe has several columns but the two columns I am interested in look something like:

```
Last Attempt      Time of Last Submission  
15               2019-09-01 17:18:43.800202  
127              2019-09-01 17:18:43.822987  
148              2019-09-01 17:18:43.830904  
15               2019-09-01 17:18:43.853714  
NaN                         NaN  
134              2019-09-01 17:18:43.877629
```

When I try plotting like this I get the error:

```
cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values
```

I thought NaN values would be ignored when plotting? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It would be `plt.scatter('Time of Last Submission', 'Last Attempt', data=df)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert column to datetimes by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `errors='coerce'` for replace non datetimes strings to missing values (`NaT`) and then use `plt.scatter`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df['Time of Last Submission'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time of Last Submission'], errors='coerce')
plt.scatter(df['Time of Last Submission'], df['Last Attempt'])

#ImportanceOfBeingErnest solution from comments
#plt.scatter('Time of Last Submission', 'Last Attempt', data=df)
```

because:

```
df.plot.scatter('Time of Last Submission', 'Last Attempt')
```

> ValueError: scatter requires x column to be numeric

Comment: When I tried this I got the error "ValueError: Given date string not likely a datetime."

Comment: This got me the plot! I should be able to take it from here! Thanks!